# How to expand job parameters and write it to a dataset using EZACFSM1 or any other way?

Tags: parameters, mainframe, jcl

I want to expand the parameters supplied in a job and write it to a dataset. Tried using EZACFSM1 utility to do this but the params don't seem to expand. The code I tried is:

Proc:

```
   //STEP0100 EXEC PGM=EZACFSM1                                         
   //SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=name_of_dataset                                     
   //SYSIN     DD *
   $EXP IS BLABLA
   /*
```

The value (say for example 'FOUR') for $EXP is passed in the job.

Expected output:
Out Dataset containing the following:

```
FOUR IS BLABLA
```

Actual output:
Out Dataset containing the following:

```
$EXP IS BLABLA
```

Comment: I believe EZACFSM1 substitutes **system** symbols, see https://www.ibm.com/support/libraryserver_os390/BOOKS/IEA1E241/2.2.2 and http://www.mvsforums.com/helpboards/viewtopic.php?t=2752

Comment: Thanks. I thought it could be used for JCL symbols as well. Any other way this could be achieved?

Comment: You can pass the parameters to a program and have it write the file. Rexx or Rexx/ISFP dialog manager is another option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, [EZACFSM1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=considerations-mvs-system-symbols) is for substituting system symbols.  For the symbols you're talking about you need a different method.

You could write your own program in your preferred language that accepts parameters and writes them to a dataset.  It's trivial, and many shops already have such a utility.  Ask your coworkers.

If your shop licenses either [DFSORT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=usfc-using-set-proc-symbols-in-dfsort-icetool-statements) or Syncsort, you could use its JPn feature to write up to 10 symbols to a dataset.

Comment: I got the expected result by exporting symlist and using IEBGENER with option SYMBOLS=JCLONLY. But when I try to use this SYSUT2 dataset as SYSUT1 in next step (IEBGENER again) to concat few files and write it to another, it doesnt work.

Comment: Ask another question about that.  Maybe explain your end goal.

Comment: This should not happen. Post your JCL for this case.